# Target element is given and find the ceiling of that element

Tags: java

**What I tried**
*here I've used order agnostic binary search*

*I've tried creating a method called webs inside which I declared a boolean variable to check whether the array is sorted in ascending or descending order(considering that order in unknown) and further I used an if condition for the same.*

```
//find the ceiling of a number
//ceiling of a given number is the smallest element
//in the array greater than or equal to target element

public class webs{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int arr[] = {-18, -12, -4, 0, 2, 3, 4, 15, 16, 18, 22, 45, 89};
        int target = 45;
        int sol = ceiling(arr, target);
        System.out.println(sol);
    }
    static int ceiling(int arr[], int target){
        int ans = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int start = 0;
        int end = arr.length-1;
        while(start <= end){
            int mid = start + (end - start)/2;
            boolean isAsc = arr[start] < arr[end];

            if(isAsc){
                if(arr[mid] < target){
                    start = mid + 1;
                } else{
                    end = mid - 1;
                }
            }else{
                if(arr[mid] > target){
                    start = mid + 1;
                }else{
                    end = mid - 1;
                }
            }
            for(int nums: arr){
                if(nums > target){
                    if(nums > ans){
                        ans = nums;
                    }
                }
            }
            return ans;
        }
        return start;
    }
}
```

*I want it to return ceiling of the target element*

**Output**
*it is returning the greatest number present in the array*

Comment: Apart from the code if possible please share the explanation of your code and the mistakes I've made. Thank you :)

Comment: what should be returned if the target is greater than all the values in the array?

Comment: That wasn't actually defined in the question.. So no idea

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is simply perform a normal binary search.  If the target is found at index i, then the ceiling is at i.  If the target is not found, then the ceiling is the index where it stops.

```
   static int ceiling(int[] arr, int target){
      int low = 0, high = arr.length-1;
      while(true){
         int mid = (low+high)/2;
         
         if      (low >= high)         return arr[low];
         
         if      (arr[mid] == target)  return arr[mid];
         else if (target > arr[mid])   low  = mid+1;
         else if (target < arr[mid])   high = mid-1;
      }
   }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int arr[] = {-18, -12, -4, 0, 2, 3, 4, 15, 16, 18, 22, 45, 89, 100};
        int target = 31;
        int sol = ceiling(arr, target);
        
        System.out.println(sol);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.I also have a doubt this code may give resource leak due to while(true).?

Comment: You mean it might go into an infinite loop?  The reason it won't is that ```low``` and ```high``` are always updated and eventually make ```low >= high``` is true or ```arr[mid] == target``` is ```true```.  This is no different from the recursive version of binary search.  Recursion is just an infinite loop like ```while (true)```. The base cases terminates the recursion just as the base cases will stop the loop.  I use while(true) often in my programs simply because it's cleaner and I don't have to introduce any additional boolean variables.